# How to properly set mapping for date and time and how to filter them in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Search for date does not return documents that really have to be.
No error messages.

Below there are three jsons: mapping, request and the first found doc

```
{
  "hello_world_schedule_fields": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "YYYY-MM-DD"
        },
        "datetime": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "is_free": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "quest_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "time": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "HH:mm"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":{
        "term":{
          "quest_id":722
        }
      },
      "must":{
        "range":{
          "date":{
            "lte":"2019-06-01"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from":0,
  "size":9999
}
```

```
{
  "id":4836777,
  "quest_id":722,
  "datetime":"2019-06-24 10:15",
  "price":400,
  "is_free":"true",
  "created_at":null,
  "updated_at":null,
  "date":"2019-06-24",
  "time":"10:15"
}
```

All found docs have quest_id: 722 but the dates are wrong.
Minimal existing date in my index is 2019-06-24 but I want to search for dates less than 2019-06-01 so nothing should be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats) is wrong: it should be `yyyy-MM-dd` (i.e. lowercase `y` and `d`)

- `D` (uppercase D) is day of year (not day of month)
- `Y` (uppercase Y) is week-based year (not year)